# Wide landscape tabular doesn't fit

Tags: tables, landscape, horizontal

So I'm making this table for a assignment at school but it didn't fit. After making it use landscape it still cuts off at the sides. Is there some way I can let it continue on another page or make this fit?

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{Bewijsmateriaal}
        \label{tab:bewijsmateriaal1}
        \begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
            \hline
            \textbf{Bewijsmateriaal}            & \textbf{Vingerafdruk} & \textbf{Zwarte Stift} & \textbf{Bodem} & \textbf{Witte Stof} & \textbf{Bloedkleurige Vlekken} & \textbf{DNA} & \textbf{Voetsporen} & \textbf{Kogelsporen} & \textbf{Vuurwapen Vergunning} & \textbf{Strafblad} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Egbert Sanders}             & Vinger 06 & Stift 01 & Bodem 01  & Stof 01 (C) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Jolien Sanders-van Opdam}   &   & Stift 01 & Bodem 02 & Stof 04 (E) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Lars Sanders}               &   & Stift 01 & Bodem 03 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Ren\'e Claasens}            &   &   & Bodem 04 & Stof 02 (A) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Mieke Helder}               &   &   & Bodem 05 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Rachel Janssen}             &   & Stift 02 &   & Stof 03 (B) & Vlek 01 &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Katie Schipper}             &   & Stift 02 & Bodem 06 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Merel Schooneveld}          &   &   & Bodem 07 &  Stof 05 (F/Pd) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Huub Henselmans}            &   & Stift 03 & Bodem 08 &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Tobar Yoska}                &   &   & Bodem 09 &    & Vlek 02 &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Roger de Jager}             & Vinger 03  &   & Bodem 10 &  Stof 06 (D) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Robert Vink}                &   & Stift 04 &   &   &  Vlek 03 &   &   &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Hannah Hoogendoorn}         & Vinger 07 & Stift 05 & Bodem 11 & Stof Onbekend &   &   & Voet 1 &   &   &  \\
            \textbf{Plaats Delict}              & Vinger 01 / Vinger 02 / Vinger 03 & Stift Kaart / Stift Dreigbrief & Bodem 12 &   &   & DNA 1 / DNA 2 & Voet 2 &   &   & 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

[image: Image of Tabular not fitting]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: To make the table narrower, you could allow linebreaks, at least inside of the column headers.

Comment: How can I do this @leandriis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A place to start from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\scriptsize}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{4pt}
        \caption{Bewijsmateriaal}
        \label{tab:bewijsmateriaal1}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{10}{c}@{}}
            \toprule
            \thead{Bewijs-\\materiaal}            & \thead{Vingerafdruk} & \thead{Zwarte\\ Stift} & \thead{Bodem} & \thead{Witte\\ Stof} & \thead{Bloedkleurige\\ Vlekken} & \thead{DNA} & \thead{Voetsporen} & \thead{Kogelsporen} & \thead{Vuurwapen\\ Vergunning} & \thead{Strafblad} \\ \midrule
            \textbf{Egbert Sanders}             & Vinger 06 & Stift 01 & Bodem 01  & Stof 01 (C) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Jolien Sanders-van Opdam}   &   & Stift 01 & Bodem 02 & Stof 04 (E) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Lars Sanders}               &   & Stift 01 & Bodem 03 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Ren\'e Claasens}            &   &   & Bodem 04 & Stof 02 (A) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Mieke Helder}               &   &   & Bodem 05 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Rachel Janssen}             &   & Stift 02 &   & Stof 03 (B) & Vlek 01 &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Katie Schipper}             &   & Stift 02 & Bodem 06 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Merel Schooneveld}          &   &   & Bodem 07 &  \makecell[t]{Stof 05\\ (F/Pd)} &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Huub Henselmans}            &   & Stift 03 & Bodem 08 &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Tobar Yoska}                &   &   & Bodem 09 &    & Vlek 02 &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Roger de Jager}             & Vinger 03  &   & Bodem 10 &  Stof 06 (D) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Robert Vink}                &   & Stift 04 &   &   &  Vlek 03 &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Hannah Hoogendoorn}         & Vinger 07 & Stift 05 & Bodem 11 & Stof Onbekend &   &   & Voet 1 &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
            \textbf{Plaats Delict}              & \makecell[t]{Vinger 01 /\\ Vinger 02 /\\ Vinger 03} & \makecell[t]{Stift Kaart /\\ Stift\\ Dreigbrief} & Bodem 12 &   &   & \makecell[tl]{DNA 1 /\\ DNA 2} & Voet 2 &   &   & \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, I used `\makecell` and `\thead` from the `makecell` package in order to add manual linebreaks in some of the cells with lengthier contents, as well as in the column headers. I also reduced the font size using `\footnotesize`, as well as the horizontal white space between columns using `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}`. Using `@{}` I also removed the white space left of the first and right or the last column in order to save some more space. In order to make sure, the table is exactly as wide as the available linewidth, I used `tabularx` and the flexible width `X` type column. Since the contents of `X` type columns are by default justified, I changed that alignment to left aligned using `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X`. Lastly, I used `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package to provide some structure for the table.
I kept the bold facing of the column headers and of the contents of the first column, but you could save quite a lot of space by using normalfont for all table entries.

Comment: Thanks! But can you add a bit of a explanation what this code is doing?

Comment: @DaanBreur: I just updated my answer to add some short explanations on parts of the code. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another `tabularx`-based solution. It uses a `sidewaystable` environment, `X`-type columns for the 10 data columns, and doesn't use *any* `\textbf` directives in order to economize on scarce horizontal space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Bewijsmateriaal\strut}
\label{tab:bewijsmateriaal1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{10}{L} @{}}
        \toprule
        Bewijsmateriaal 
        & Vinger\-afdruk & Zwarte Stift & Bodem & Witte Stof & Bloedkleurige Vlekken 
        & DNA & Voetsporen & Kogel\-sporen & Vuurwapen Vergunning & Strafblad \\ 
        \midrule
        Egbert Sanders             & Vinger 06 & Stift 01 & Bodem 01 & Stof 01 (C) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Jolien Sanders-van Opdam   &           & Stift 01 & Bodem 02 & Stof 04 (E) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Lars Sanders               &           & Stift 01 & Bodem 03 &        &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Ren\'e Claasens            &           &          & Bodem 04 & Stof 02 (A) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Mieke Helder               &           &          & Bodem 05 &        &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Rachel Janssen             &           & Stift 02 &          & Stof 03 (B) & Vlek 01 &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Katie Schipper             &           & Stift 02 & Bodem 06 &    &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Merel Schooneveld          &           &          & Bodem 07 & Stof 05 (F/Pd) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Huub Henselmans            &           & Stift 03 & Bodem 08 &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Tobar Yoska                &           &          & Bodem 09 &    & Vlek 02 &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Roger de Jager             & Vinger 03 &          & Bodem 10 &  Stof 06 (D) &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Robert Vink                &           & Stift 04 &          &   &  Vlek 03 &   &   &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Hannah Hoogendoorn         & Vinger 07 & Stift 05 & Bodem 11 & Stof Onbekend &   &   & Voet 1 &   &   &  \\ \addlinespace
        Plaats Delict              & Vinger 01\slash Vinger 02\slash Vinger 03 & Stift Kaart\slash Stift Dreigbrief & Bodem 12   
                                       &   &   & DNA 1\slash DNA 2 & Voet 2 &   &   & \\ 
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
In correction of the MWE are considered suggestions given in @Mico comment. Thank you very much!

One more solution with `sidewaystable` float environment and use of the `tabularray` package. For lines rules in table are used rules as defined in `tabularbooks` package (loaded by `\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
        \caption{Bewijsmateriaal}
        \label{tab:bewijsmateriaal1}
\begin{tblr}{row{1}  = {c, b, font=\bfseries},
             colsep  = {3pt},
             colspec = {@{} l *{8}{X[0.95,l]} X[1.2,l] X[0.8,l]@{}},
             column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             } 
            \toprule
Bewijsmateriaal             & Vinger\-afdruk  
                                        & Zwarte Stift  
                                                    & Bodem     & {Witte\\ Stof}    
                                                                                & Bloed\-kleurige Vlekken  
                            & DNA       & Voets\-poren
                                                    & Kogel\-sporen  
                                                                & Vuurwapen Vergunning  
                                                                                & Strafblad  \\
            \midrule
Egbert Sanders              & Vinger 06 & Stift 01  & Bodem 01  & Stof 01 (C)   &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Jolien Sanders-van Opdam    &           & Stift 01  & Bodem 02  & Stof 04 (E)   &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Lars Sanders                &           & Stift 01  & Bodem 03  &               &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Ren\'e Claasens             &           &           & Bodem 04  & Stof 02 (A)   &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Mieke Helder                &           &           & Bodem 05  &               &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Rachel Janssen              &           & Stift 02  &           & Stof 03 (B)   & Vlek 01 
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Katie Schipper              &           & Stift 02  & Bodem 06  &               &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Merel Schooneveld           &           &           & Bodem 07  & Stof 05 (F/Pd)&   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Huub Henselmans             &           & Stift 03  & Bodem 08  &               &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Tobar Yoska                 &           &           & Bodem 09  &               & Vlek 02 
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Roger de Jager              & Vinger 03 &           & Bodem 10  & Stof 06 (D)   &   
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Robert Vink                 &           & Stift 04  &           &               & Vlek 03 
                            &           &           &           &               &   \\
Hannah Hoogendoorn          & Vinger 07 & Stift 05  & Bodem 11  & Stof Onbekend &   
                            &           & Voet 1    &           &               &   \\
Plaats Delict               & {Vinger 01\slash\\ Vinger 02\slash\\ Vinger 03} 
                                        & Stift Kaart\slash Stift Dreigbrief 
                                                    & Bodem 12  &               &   
                            & {DNA 1\slash\\ DNA 2}
                                        & Voet 2    &           &               &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you may have lost the table's final column. For sure, "Strafblad" should be a header by itself, not part of the preceding header. You may also want to replace the OP's use of " / " with `\slash ` in order to get better linebreaks.

Comment: @Mico, you are right (again)! Thank you very much. I edited my answer I consider your comment.